# Android Q - External Storage (FileNotFoundException) Access Denied

Tags: android, android-permissions, filenotfoundexception, android-fileprovider

My app has a feature that allows to upload and download photos (one at a time). I have no issues on Pie and older (minSdk 21). After updating my app to target Android Q however, I no longer can take photos or download photos. I continually get a FileNotFoundException:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/mydirectory/IMG_20190924_135818.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

**Downloading**

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File downloadedPhoto = FileUtils.createFile(dir, photoDto.getFileName(), photoDto.getBytes());
```

**Uploading Using Camera**

```
Uri contentURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PhotosActivity.this, BuildConfig.FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, PhotoUtils.getPhotoUploadCameraImageTemporaryFile(getFilesDir()));

try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null, null)) {
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        String size = cursor.isNull(sizeIndex) ? "Unknown" : cursor.getString(sizeIndex);
        String fileType = getContentResolver().getType(contentURI);

        File dir = PhotoUtils.getPhotoAlbumDirectory(PhotosActivity.this);
        File capturedImageFile = PhotoUtils.createPhotoUploadFile(dir);
        PhotoUtils.copyPhotoToTemporaryFile(PhotosActivity.this, contentURI, dir, capturedImageFile);
....
```

FYI the Exception happens when creating the downloaded file, and when copying to the temporary file.I see that the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is now deprecated so I assume that is a part of the problem. There is a suggestion to replace it with getExternalFilesDir but I need to ensure the photos remain on the device if the user uninstalls the application. I also have permissions for reading/writing to external storage and camera granted so I don't believe it has to do with that.

I am trying to find examples on how to migrate to the "new way" but I am having a hard time. Even the link to "scoped access" documents on the Android site returns 404. From what I have read, it seems like I need to migrate to using MediaStore but finding a tutorial is proving to be difficult as well.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you need to have your app working again you can lower target SDK down to 28 or [opt-out](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped#opt-out-of-filtered-view) of scoped storage until you finish transitioning into newer api.

Comment: "I continually get a FileNotFoundException" -- that is because [you no longer have access to most of external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html). "From what I have read, it seems like I need to migrate to using MediaStore but finding a tutorial is proving to be difficult as well" -- I cover it in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Q/). [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/v0.5/ConferenceVideos) from that book demonstrates downloading videos to `MediaStore`.

Comment: Thanks @Pawel. I opted out for now.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, I read your article and now I am even more concerned that they are flat out removing legacy storage no matter what targetSdk we use? Thanks for the sample code but I am not very familiar with Kotlin and I am more concerned about how to transition properly with saving to the Downloads folder and taking pictures and saving them to my custom folder in external storage.

Comment: "how to transition properly with saving to the Downloads folder" -- you don't have access to that, unless the user grants it to you via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and you work with it via `ContentResolver` and `DocumentFile`. "and taking pictures and saving them to my custom folder in external storage" -- for that, since it is media, you can use `MediaStore`. "After updating my app to target Android Q" -- leave your app at `targetSdkVersion 28` for the time being. You will be forced to target 29 next year, but that gives you time.

Comment: @CommonsWare Wait what? Saving to the Downloads folder requires another permission and the use of a different API to do it? I just want to be able to save a picture or a pdf or whatever to the Downloads folder.

Comment: "Saving to the Downloads folder requires another permission and the use of a different API to do it?" -- not a permission, but yes, a different API. However, I forgot about the new `MediaStore.Downloads` option when I wrote my earlier comment. I have not tried this, and so YMMV, but in theory you can save to the `Downloads` directory using the recipe outlined in that example I linked to, with a different base `Uri`. But, in either case (`MediaStore.Downloads` or the Storage Access Framework), it will be a different API than simply writing to the filesystem.